# JQUERY .val not working......HTML table created using PHP unable to get the specific row value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a HTML table using a echoing each row in a  by looping through the rows of the database which is stored into the PHP fetch array function after retrieving from the database using the SELECT statement. Along with this I added another column which is a submit button hence it looped through every each row.

I did this so that I could get the "ID" of each row when submitted and run another script using AJAX JQUERY. But the problem is that my javascript code only gets the value of the first row when submited and it is unresponsive to the other rows.

Table code:

```
<form id="mainform">
<table>
<th>ID</th>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='hiddenfield' value='$ID'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='select' /></td>";
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#mainform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#testdiv").empty();
    $.get("boom.php", { ID: $("#hiddenfield").val() },
    function(data) {
        $("#newdiv").append(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

With this AJAX code I am trying to get the value to boom.php where now I am just testing if the correct value has been parsed.

Anyone can help me out? I am stuck...

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: what happens when you go to `boom.php` directly?  Are you sure it's on the same relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems: first, you can't reuse the same `id` on multiple fields. They must be unique. Use a `class`:

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' class='hiddenfield' value='$ID'></td>";
```

even then, `.val()` will only return the first matching item's value.

Assuming you want to pass a list of ID values, you'll need to build the list yourself:

```
$("#mainform").on("submit", function(){
$("#testdiv").empty();

var vals = [];
$('.hiddenfield').each(
  function() {
    var field = $(this);
    vals.push(field.val());
  }
);
$.get("boom.php", { ID: JSON.stringify(vals) },
```

will pass a string version of the list (e.g. `["1","2","3"]`);

If you want to send each ID separately, do so within the `each` loop:

```
$('.hiddenfield').each(
  function() {
    var field = $(this);
    $.get("boom.php", { ID: field.val() },
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi there can you advice on only sending one row